# What environment should PCNTL be used in?

Tags: php, pcntl

The PHP manual states:

> Process Control should not be enabled within a web server environment
>   and unexpected results may happen if any Process Control functions are
>   used within a web server environment.

However, the manual does not state what environment PCNTL should be used in. I am new to PCNTL and want to know what environments PCNTL scripts are run on. I wanted to use PCNTL for the purpose of writing a daemon script that runs on my server but, I feel confused about PCNTL intention, as I see many articles using PCNTL to write daemon scripts.

I looked for an article or question explaining what environments PCNTL is run on but, maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about it's intended use?

Comment: Environments that are not web servers. Is your *server* a *web server*?

Comment: @Ken White Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Ken White Yes my server is a web server. Are there other types of servers?

Comment: There are all kinds of applications and servers that are not web servers. But you already know that you're writing a web server and that the documentation says it's not suitable for web servers, so it's not appropriate for your server. If you have a specific question (*Is PCNTL suitable for this task?*), we can answer it. *Create me a list of all the places it *can* be used except web servers?* is not appropriate here.

Comment: Well looking at the definition of a server on wiki cleared up a lot of confusion.

Comment: @Ken White I just wanted to understand the intended use of PCNTL. The manual just points out what not to use it on and not what to use it on. It is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Ken White Wiki points to other servers like mail servers and database servers. A simple example like that cleared up a lot of confusion for me.

Comment: A little research (like Wiki) on your part before posting here would have cleared up that confusion as well, wouldn't it? And the fact that you've done that research in the last 9 minutes pretty much indicates you didn't do much research before posting here. You're supposed to do that research first.

Comment: @Ken White I have been researching the subject for two whole days. I have read the entire section on PHP manual for PCNTL. I have read dozens of SO questions on the subject in an attempt to understand this. Plus I have read several tutorials as well. It wasn't until reading your comments that I considered reading the definition of a server on Wiki. Something I regret never having done in my 9 years of programming. So yes Ken, I felt I had done all the research I could. I only come to SO when I feel I have reached a brick wall.

Comment: @Ken White Furthermore, none of the articles, questions, or answers I have found discuss anything remotely close to PCNTL use on other servers such as mail servers etc. Had they done so, I would have probably had a better understanding. That being said, if the PHP manual maybe gave some examples, that would be very helpful. In my many years of programming PHP I had always assumed the language was used solely for the web. It is now that I am learning that PHP can also be used in other applications other than websites. It truly is a powerful language.

Comment: Also whenever I read the PHP manual, I make it a point to read the user contributed notes. Those come in handy a lot.

Comment: I have no idea what you're going on and on about, but I'd appreciate it if you'd stop. The flags popping up in my inbox are rather annoying. I made the comment about the research because a) there is no indication in your original question that you did any research other than the section of the docs you quoted, b) I don't know you, so I know nothing about what research you typically do anywhere about anything, and c) you found information that seemed to clarify things for you within 9 minutes of my original comment. That's all. I meant nothing else by the comment.

Comment: @Ken White You are not very helpful. Rather you come off as hostile. Which defeats the intention of SO. I am not here to harass you. I am here seeking help. There is a difference. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out, PCNTL is used on servers such as mail servers, database servers, file servers, and others. It had never occurred to me that servers are not just used for the web and that PHP can be used outside of a web environment. These types of servers are new to me hence why I was so confused on the matter.